# Changing file locations based on staging environment

Tags: c#, asp.net, git, asp.net-web-api

I am unsure how to properly ask this question so I am going to try and explain what I am trying to do. I am trying to learn how to properly setup my projects for Continuous Integration.

**Current Setup:**

- Working with a .Net framework web api project.
- I have two branches **Development** and **Master**(Production)
- I have various file locations within my app pointing to some resources on our network drives (csv files, text files, etc)

Whenever a new feature is needed I plan on creating it in my dev branch, once tested and good I would like to merge that feature into my master(production) branch. I need to be able to do this without affecting the file location paths what so ever. Not sure if I am just going about this all the wrong way.

**What I am current doing:**

I have static string variables in my application referencing the location like so:

```
private string filelocation1 = @"\\NetworkDrive\Folder1\data.csv";
private string filelocation2 = @"\\NetworkDrive\Folder2\data.csv";
private string filelocation3 = @"\\NetworkDrive\Folder3\data.csv";
```

Which is obviously not what I want to keep doing going forward if I am going to be using different staging environments which should also be using staging file locations that does not touch the actual production data.

**My Question:**

So basically what I am asking is what are the different ways I can go about:

1. Changing file location paths based on branches and/or based on publish packages (like the web.config transforms?)
2. Bonus: If you could explain how this is managed with TFS / Git Repos that would be fantastic.

I have traditionally not needed to have separate environments for the in house applications I have been creating but in order to prevent bugs going forward I want to start learning the proper methods to manage resources between branches/deployment environments for Web projects

Comment: I sometimes set some static variables based on `Environment.MachineName`.

Comment: That could work but I was thinking more along the lines of environment variables and things like that. Where there is a resource file that is managed between branches. Not sure what the traditional way of doing that is. I would also like other developers to be able to work on this later without having to change all those obscure settings throughout the app. @VDWWD

Comment: Resource files? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/resources/creating-resource-files-for-desktop-apps

Comment: @VDWWD yeah like resource files. Now how do you go about managing different resource files between your branches? If I want to merge a feature from my dev branch into my production branch, how can I do so without overwriting the resource files?

Comment: That I don't know unfortunately. But you can have 1 resource file for multiple language localizations I believe. Maybe the same goes for general resources.